# Mongo TypeError: MongoClient.close is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an application that closes it's database connection after a certain time of inactivity. The problem is, I can't kill it's connection with MongoClient.close() because it's always returns that a error "TypeError: MongoClient.close is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let mongo = {};
let db;
let disconnectTimer;
let retryTimer;
let disconnect; //Used to prevent mongo from reconnect.

mongo.disconnect = () => {
    disconnect = true;
    try {
        MongoClient.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn("Error closing connection to Database =", error);
        throw {
            statusCode: 404,
            error: error.toString(),
            reason: "",
            details: ""
        };
    }
}
mongo.getDB = () => {
    if (typeof db !== "undefined" && !disconnect)
        return db;
    else
        return connect().catch((error) => {
            throw error
        }).then((db) => {return db});
}

module.exports = mongo;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If db is used as the Mongo DB connection instance,then please try to use dB.close() instead of MongoClient.close().

Comment: I followed your instruction but got the same error.

Comment: Please share the package.json file contents

Comment: Added package.json.

Comment: Which variable is the DB connection instance?

Comment: I use db as the dB connection instance.

Comment: Try to use db.close()

Comment: I have edited the answer,please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = (callback, collectionName) => {
    mongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then((connection) => {
        const db = connection.db(dbName);
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

        callback(collection, ObjectId);

        connection.close();
    });
}
```